# Replacing Ubuntu with Windows 8.1

Tags: grub2, windows-8

I am trying to wipe out Ubuntu 13.10 from my laptop and install Windows 8.1 instead. I formatted my hard drive and deleted the old partition.

Now when I try and boot I get  this error:

```
error: no such partition 
Entering rescue mode 
grub rescue >
```

Has anyone else had issues with this? How do I reset it to install Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted your partitions than there is nothing left to boot, and you may have also deleted your /boot if you had one. To install windows 8 place the cd or usb in and try to boot from it by hitting esc or whatever your pc manufacturer specified. Windows 8 should reinstall its boot loader by itself.